# numpy 3d to 2d transformation based on 2d mask array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an ndarray like this:

```
>>> a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I know I can get the maximum along a certain axis using `np.max(axis=...)`:

```
>>> a.max(axis=2)
array([[ 2,  5,  8],
       [11, 14, 17],
       [20, 23, 26]])
```

Alternatively, I could get the **indices** along that axis which correspond to the maximum values from:

```
>>> indices = a.argmax(axis=2)
>>> indices
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

My question -- Given the array `indices` and the array `a`, is there an elegant way to reproduce the array the array returned by `a.max(axis=2)`?

This would probably work:

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np
def apply_mask(field,indices):
    data = np.empty(indices.shape)

    #It seems highly likely that there is a more numpy-approved way to do this.
    idx = [range(i) for i in indices.shape]
    for idx_tup,zidx in zip(it.product(*idx),indices.flat):
        data[idx_tup] = field[idx_tup+(zidx,)]
    return data
```

But, it seems pretty hacky/inefficient.  It also doesn't allow for me to use this with any axis other than the "last" axis.  Is there a numpy function (or some use of magical numpy indexing) to make this work?  The naive `a[:,:,a.argmax(axis=2)]` doesn't work.

**UPDATE**:

It seems the following also works (and is a little nicer):

```
import numpy as np
def apply_mask(field,indices):
    data = np.empty(indices.shape)

    for idx_tup,zidx in np.ndenumerate(indices):
        data[idx_tup] = field[idx_tup+(zidx,)]

    return data
```

---

I would like to do this because I would like to extract the indices based on the data in 1 array (typically using `argmax(axis=...)`) and use those indices to pull data out of a bunch of other (equivalently shaped) arrays.  I'm open to alternative ways to accomplish this (e.g. using boolean masked arrays).  However, I like the "safety" that I get using these "index" arrays.  With this I am guaranteed to have the right number of elements to create a new array which looks like a 2d "slice" through the 3d field.

Comment: After scouring numpy/scipy for several minutes, I agree with your self-answer(s). Ultimately, it's more readable and practical to go the "hacky" route. Nevertheless, you may be interested in functions `ravel`, `ravel_multi_index`, `unravel_index`, `flat`, and `flatten`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some magic numpy indexing that will do what you want, but unfortunately it's pretty unreadable.

```
def apply_mask(a, indices, axis):
    magic_index = [np.arange(i) for i in indices.shape]
    magic_index = np.ix_(*magic_index)
    magic_index = magic_index[:axis] + (indices,) + magic_index[axis:]
    return a[magic_index]
```

or equally unreadable:

```
def apply_mask(a, indices, axis):
    magic_index = np.ogrid[tuple(slice(i) for i in indices.shape)]
    magic_index.insert(axis, indices)
    return a[magic_index]
```

Comment: I actually like the `ogrid` route a little better than `np.ix_`.  For whatever reason, `np.ix_` always seemed a little too magical for my taste.

Answer (score -1):

I use `index_at()` to create the full index:

```
import numpy as np

def index_at(idx, shape, axis=-1):
    if axis<0:
        axis += len(shape)
    shape = shape[:axis] + shape[axis+1:]
    index = list(np.ix_(*[np.arange(n) for n in shape]))
    index.insert(axis, idx)
    return tuple(index)

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 4, 5))

axis = 1
idx = np.argmax(a, axis=axis)
print a[index_at(idx, a.shape, axis=axis)]
print np.max(a, axis=axis)
```