# Maximum value of first column

Tags: python, max

I have an array like this:

```
elements=[['1', '1', '2'], ['2', '2', '3'], ['3', '3', '4'], ['4', '4', '5'], ['5', '5', '6'], ['6', '6', '7'], ['7', '7', '8'], ['8', '8', '9'], ['9', '9', '10'], ['10', '10', '11'], ['11', '11', '12'], ['12', '12', '13'], ['13', '13', '14'], ['14', '14', '15'], ['15', '15', '16'], ['16', '16', '17'], ['17', '17', '18'], ['18', '18', '19'], ['19', '19', '20'], ['20', '20', '21'], ['21', '21', '22'], ['22', '22', '23'], ['23', '23', '24'], ['24', '24', '25'], ['25', '25', '26'], ['26', '26', '27'], ['27', '27', '28'], ['28', '28', '29'], ['29', '29', '30'], ['30', '30', '31'], ['31', '32', '33'], ['32', '33', '34'], ['33', '34', '35'], ['34', '35', '36'], ['35', '36', '37'], ['36', '37', '38'], ['37', '38', '39'], ['38', '39', '40'], ['39', '40', '41'], ['40', '41', '42'], ['41', '42', '43'], ['42', '43', '44'], ['43', '44', '45'], ['44', '45', '46'], ['45', '46', '47'], ['46', '47', '48'], ['47', '48', '49'], ['48', '49', '50'], ['49', '50', '51'], ['50', '51', '52'], ['51', '52', '53'], ['52', '53', '54'], ['53', '54', '55'], ['54', '55', '56'], ['55', '56', '57'], ['56', '57', '58'], ['57', '58', '59'], ['58', '59', '60'], ['59', '60', '61'], ['60', '61', '62'], ['61', '63', '64'], ['62', '64', '65'], ['63', '65', '66'], ['64', '66', '67'], ['65', '67', '68'], ['66', '68', '69'], ['67', '69', '70'], ['68', '70', '71'], ['69', '71', '72'], ['70', '72', '73'], ['71', '73', '74'], ['72', '74', '75'], ['73', '75', '76'], ['74', '76', '77'], ['75', '77', '78'], ['76', '78', '79'], ['77', '79', '80'], ['78', '80', '81'], ['79', '81', '82'], ['80', '82', '83'], ['81', '83', '84'], ['82', '84', '85'], ['83', '85', '86'], ['84', '86', '87'], ['85', '87', '88'], ['86', '88', '89'], ['87', '89', '90'], ['88', '90', '91'], ['89', '91', '92'], ['90', '92', '93'], ['91', '94', '95'], ['92', '95', '96'], ['93', '96', '97'], ['94', '97', '98'], ['95', '98', '99'], ['96', '99', '100'], ['97', '100', '101'], ['98', '101', '102'], ['99', '102', '103'], ['100', '103', '104'], ['101', '104', '105'], ['102', '105', '106'], ['103', '106', '107'], ['104', '107', '108'], ['105', '108', '109'], ['106', '109', '110'], ['107', '110', '111'], ['108', '111', '112'], ['109', '112', '113'], ['110', '113', '114'], ['111', '114', '115'], ['112', '115', '116'], ['113', '116', '117'], ['114', '117', '118'], ['115', '118', '119'], ['116', '119', '120'], ['117', '120', '121'], ['118', '121', '122'], ['119', '122', '123'], ['120', '123', '124'], ['121', '125', '126'], ['122', '126', '127'], ['123', '127', '128'], ['124', '128', '129'], ['125', '129', '130'], ['126', '130', '131'], ['127', '131', '132'], ['128', '132', '133'], ['129', '133', '134'], ['130', '134', '135'], ['131', '135', '136'], ['132', '136', '137'], ['133', '137', '138'], ['134', '138', '139'], ['135', '139', '140'], ['136', '141', '142'], ['137', '142', '143'], ['138', '143', '144'], ['139', '144', '145'], ['140', '145', '146'], ['141', '146', '147'], ['142', '147', '148'], ['143', '148', '149'], ['144', '149', '150'], ['145', '150', '151'], ['146', '151', '152'], ['147', '152', '153'], ['148', '153', '154'], ['149', '154', '155'], ['150', '155', '156'], ['151', '157', '158'], ['152', '158', '159'], ['153', '159', '160'], ['154', '160', '161'], ['155', '161', '162'], ['156', '162', '163'], ['157', '163', '164'], ['158', '164', '165'], ['159', '165', '166'], ['160', '166', '167'], ['161', '167', '168'], ['162', '168', '169'], ['163', '169', '170'], ['164', '170', '171'], ['165', '171', '172'], ['166', '172', '173'], ['167', '173', '174'], ['168', '174', '175'], ['169', '175', '176'], ['170', '176', '177'], ['171', '177', '178'], ['172', '178', '179'], ['173', '179', '180'], ['174', '180', '181'], ['175', '181', '182'], ['176', '182', '183'], ['177', '183', '184'], ['178', '184', '185'], ['179', '185', '186'], ['180', '186', '187'], ['181', '188', '189'], ['182', '189', '190'], ['183', '190', '191'], ['184', '191', '192'], ['185', '192', '193'], ['186', '193', '194'], ['187', '194', '195'], ['188', '195', '196'], ['189', '196', '197'], ['190', '197', '198'], ['191', '198', '199'], ['192', '199', '200'], ['193', '200', '201'], ['194', '201', '202'], ['195', '202', '203'], ['196', '203', '204'], ['197', '204', '205'], ['198', '205', '206'], ['199', '206', '207'], ['200', '207', '208'], ['201', '208', '209'], ['202', '209', '210'], ['203', '210', '211'], ['204', '211', '212'], ['205', '212', '213'], ['206', '213', '214'], ['207', '214', '215'], ['208', '215', '216'], ['209', '216', '217'], ['210', '217', '218'], ['211', '219', '220'], ['212', '220', '221'], ['213', '221', '222'], ['214', '222', '223'], ['215', '223', '224'], ['216', '224', '225'], ['217', '225', '226'], ['218', '226', '227'], ['219', '227', '228'], ['220', '228', '229'], ['221', '229', '230'], ['222', '230', '231'], ['223', '231', '232'], ['224', '232', '233'], ['225', '233', '234'], ['226', '235', '236'], ['227', '236', '237'], ['228', '237', '238'], ['229', '238', '239'], ['230', '239', '240'], ['231', '240', '241'], ['232', '241', '242'], ['233', '242', '243'], ['234', '243', '244'], ['235', '244', '245'], ['236', '245', '246'], ['237', '246', '247'], ['238', '247', '248'], ['239', '248', '249'], ['240', '249', '250'], ['241', '251', '252'], ['242', '252', '253'], ['243', '253', '254'], ['244', '254', '255'], ['245', '255', '256'], ['246', '256', '257'], ['247', '257', '258'], ['248', '258', '259'], ['249', '259', '260'], ['250', '260', '261'], ['251', '261', '262'], ['252', '262', '263'], ['253', '263', '264'], ['254', '264', '265'], ['255', '265', '266'], ['256', '267', '268'], ['257', '268', '269'], ['258', '269', '270'], ['259', '270', '271'], ['260', '271', '272'], ['261', '272', '273'], ['262', '273', '274'], ['263', '274', '275'], ['264', '275', '276'], ['265', '276', '277'], ['266', '277', '278'], ['267', '278', '279'], ['268', '279', '280'], ['269', '280', '281'], ['270', '281', '282'], ['271', '283', '284'], ['272', '284', '285'], ['273', '285', '286'], ['274', '286', '287'], ['275', '287', '288'], ['276', '288', '289'], ['277', '289', '290'], ['278', '290', '291'], ['279', '291', '292'], ['280', '292', '293'], ['281', '293', '294'], ['282', '294', '295'], ['283', '295', '296'], ['284', '296', '297'], ['285', '297', '298'], ['286', '298', '299'], ['287', '299', '300'], ['288', '300', '301'], ['289', '301', '302'], ['290', '302', '303'], ['291', '303', '304'], ['292', '304', '305'], ['293', '305', '306'], ['294', '306', '307'], ['295', '307', '308'], ['296', '308', '309'], ['297', '309', '310'], ['298', '310', '311'], ['299', '311', '312'], ['300', '312', '313'], ['301', '314', '315'], ['302', '315', '316'], ['303', '316', '317'], ['304', '317', '318'], ['305', '318', '319'], ['306', '319', '320'], ['307', '320', '321'], ['308', '321', '322'], ['309', '322', '323'], ['310', '323', '324'], ['311', '324', '325'], ['312', '325', '326'], ['313', '326', '327'], ['314', '327', '328'], ['315', '328', '329'], ['316', '329', '330'], ['317', '330', '331'], ['318', '331', '332'], ['319', '332', '333'], ['320', '333', '334'], ['321', '334', '335'], ['322', '335', '336'], ['323', '336', '337'], ['324', '337', '338'], ['325', '338', '339'], ['326', '339', '340'], ['327', '340', '341'], ['328', '341', '342'], ['329', '342', '343'], ['330', '343', '344'], ['331', '345', '346'], ['332', '346', '347'], ['333', '347', '348'], ['334', '348', '349'], ['335', '349', '350'], ['336', '350', '351'], ['337', '351', '352'], ['338', '352', '353'], ['339', '353', '354'], ['340', '354', '355'], ['341', '355', '356'], ['342', '356', '357'], ['343', '357', '358'], ['344', '358', '359'], ['345', '359', '360'], ['346', '361', '362'], ['347', '362', '363'], ['348', '363', '364'], ['349', '364', '365'], ['350', '365', '366'], ['351', '366', '367'], ['352', '367', '368'], ['353', '368', '369'], ['354', '369', '370'], ['355', '370', '371'], ['356', '371', '372'], ['357', '372', '373'], ['358', '373', '374'], ['359', '374', '375'], ['360', '375', '376']]
```

I'd like to know the maximum value of the first column of this array. However I've found that problematic since I'm not used to python.

I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(elements)
numEL = a[np.argmax(a)][0]
```

but I get a wrong result. I know it is 360 but it returns 285...

Any ideas?

Comment: `max(element[0] for element in elements)` - there is probably a `numpy` way of doing this that is more efficient, however.

Comment: Hi! It returns 99. I know it is 360

Comment: `print()` your list - it doesn't contain what you think it does if you are getting `99`.

Comment: @jpcgandre, consider challenging what you 'know'.  Perhaps you've arranged the data incorrectly given the problem or stated the problem incorrectly given the data.

Comment: @jpcgandre Did you try: `np.argmax(a, axis=0)`? Without specifying the axis I get `6` as result of `argmax` and this gives an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your elements are strings, and therefore the comparisons are lexicographic.  You want to work with integers:

```
>>> elements=[['1', '1', '2'], ['99', '2', '3'],['360', '10', '11']]
>>> a = np.array(elements,dtype=int)
>>> a
array([[  1,   1,   2],
       [ 99,   2,   3],
       [360,  10,  11]])
>>> a.max(axis=0)
array([360,  10,  11])
>>> a.max(axis=0)[0]
360
```

or simply

```
>>> a[:,0]
array([  1,  99, 360])
>>> a[:,0].max()
360
```

[Note: this is how to get it to work.  As for why the code was returning a strange answer in the first place, @mgilson explains that in the comments to this answer.]

Comment: I wonder whats better ... taking the max along axis=0, or slicing the 0'th column out and taking the max of that ...

Comment: Oy, it looks like you beat me to it.  :-/  You want this one?

Comment: Nah -- Yours is more complete -- Although I'm still struggling to figure out how `'285'` could sort greater than `'360'`

Comment: Ahh ... the real problem (I think -- other than the string compare) is that `np.argmax` returns the index in the flattened array. This "flat" index is then used to index the non-flattened array and then the `0th` element gets pulled out.  OP's code is just as likely to raise an IndexError as anything else.

Comment: @mgilson: I was just trying to figure that out myself.  I admit to being a little surprised when `np.argmax(a)` returned 284!  Although I'd say "underlying" rather than "real". :^)

Comment: I remembered that little tidbit as I'd been doing a little work with `argmin` and `argmax` recently...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469302/numpy-3d-to-2d-transformation-based-on-2d-mask-array)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [3]: max(elements, key=lambda e: int(e[0]))
Out[3]: ['360', '10', '11']
```

Answer (score 1):

`max(elements, key=lambda x: x[0])` or `max(elements, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]` if you just care about the actual value of the first column and not the element that contains the maximum value

Answer (score 1):

```
maxEl = max(element[0] for element in elements)
```

Bear in mind that you're still comparing strings here! If you're trying to compare by integer, you need to make sure that you actually do that.

```
maxIntEl = max(int(element[0]) for element in elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

elements = np.array([['1', '1', '2'], ['10002', '2', '3'], ['360', '10', '11']])
print np.max([int(e) for e in elements[:, 0]])
```

or

```
elements = [['1', '1', '2'], ['10002', '2', '3'], ['360', '10', '11']]
elements = np.array([[int(e) for e in element] for element in elements])
print np.max(elements[:, 0])
```

The first snippet is more efficient since string to int conversion is done only for one column rather than doing type conversion for entire numpy array (as in 2nd snippet).

Hope it helps.